# Choose image from gallery, display in imageview and save image displayed in a new directory

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two buttons and an ImageView in my Activity. When I click on one button it would redirect to gallery and I would be able to select an image. The selected image would appear in my ImageView.
The problem now is i want the save button to save the image displayed in a new directory like it does in apps like instagram.

My layout is given below;

```
  <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="imgClick"
        android:id="@+id/imgButton"
        android:text="Select Image"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/diddyImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addMovieClick"
        android:id="@+id/addMovieButton"
        android:text="Submit Movie"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

My activity is given below

```
   public void imgClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECTED_PICTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SELECTED_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            uri = data.getData();
            diddyImageView.setImageURI(uri);

        }
}
```

The image is displayed properly, i want to save the image in a new folder and i dont know how to go about it..Any help will be appreciated..Thanks

Comment: `i want to save the image in a new folder` What about using a simple file copy?

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to open an `InputStream` on the `Uri` to the image

Step #2: Open a `FileOutputStream` on the desired file for your copy

Step #3: Use standard Java I/O to copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`

Step #4: Move all of that work into a background thread (and consider using an image-loading library to replace your `setImageURI()` call), to avoid tying up the main application thread doing all of this work